# PHP Session forms

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm having some difficulty with PHP sessions. 
The idea is to prevent users from accessing the administrator panel / pages by using the direct URL.

I have created a login form and that works well (login.php)
Once the username and password are correctly entered, the login form takes the user to the admin panel (admin.php)

However when I added the following script PHP to the (admin.php) page, it does not work. 
When I enter the username and password on the login page, it always fails and re-directs me to login.php

The script on the admin.php  is used to prevent users from accessing the page if 
the session variable is not set

ANY help greatly appreciated :)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin_panel.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">

      <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
      <input type="password" name="user_pass" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="login">Let me in.</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>




    //===================================== login.php


    <?php 

      include("includes.php");
      if(isset($_POST['login'])) { 

      echo $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['user_name']); 
      echo $user_pass  = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['user_pass']);
      $encrypt = md5($user_pass);  


       $select_user = "select * from users where user_name= '$user_name' AND user_password =    '$user_pass'";
       $run_user = mysql_query($select_user);


        if(mysql_num_rows($run_user)>0){  // what does this function DO?
        $_SESSISON['user_name'] =$user_name;      


         echo "<script> window.open('admin_panel.php?logged=You have logged in','_self' )</script>";
          }

         else {
         echo "<script> alert('Wrong details')</script>";
            } }

        ?>

    </html





    // admin.php script ====================



        <?php
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
        echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self')</script>";
        }

        else {     // ELSE CLOSED BOTTOM OF THE PAGE

        ?>


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Admin page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin_panel.css" media="all">
        </head>
        <body>



          <a href="home.php?view_comments"> comments(0)</a>
          <a href="admin_panel.php?insert_post"> Insert New Post </a>
          <a href="logout.php"> Admin Logout </a>




          <?php   

          if(isset($_GET['insert_cat'])) { 
          include("insert_cat.php");
          }

          if(isset($_GET['insert_post'])) {
          include("insert_post.php");
          }

          ?>


        </body>
        <?php } ?>   // CLOSE ELSE
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you post your login.php code. @andrew if you disabled JavaScript the login.php page wouldn't open, the admin section itself is in the else statement so it wouldn't run assuming the `user_name` session wasn't set.

Comment: Erhm, how can this page be "hacked" by simply disabling a javscript? W/o javascript you simply cannot login (becasue the session variable never gets set; depending on login.php which we don't see so far).

Comment: @MrTux ok, perhaps 'hacking' was exaggerating, but it would certainly allow me to view the page he didn't intend

Comment: @andrew: No, why do you think so?

Comment: @MrTux ah. I never noticed the `else{` should read questions more thoroughly :p

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use an authentication system from framework like Zend, Symfony, Laravel etc. than $_SESSION included in PHP.
To redirect user you can use function [header()](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.header.php)

for example:

```
header('Location: login.php');
```

it's important to set charset to 'UTF-8 without BOM' and it can't be any output before header()

Comment: Thanks Dikeyi've updated my code to show login.php and admin.php any ideas why this is not working??   Many thanks, p

Comment: Correct "$_SESSISON['user_name'] =$user_name;" to $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;

Comment: Oh, wow , I can't believe I missed that !!! You are a great man, many I'll test this out and see what happens

Comment: Your comment answers the question opposed to your "answer". Also it's [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), not BOOM.

Comment: Racja. I mean: you're right, man. It's BOM. I give the answer before code in question was edited.